# What is the best solution for working with large database table when working with DevxGrid?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, paging, large-data

I want to transform from asp.net grid to devxgrid control but I can not  determine which method is the best method for working with large table(I mean tables with more than 1000000 data rows in SQLServer 2008).

What is the best way to implement paging in this control especially when using EntityFramework ??

Answer (score 0):

You can Ref this [EntityFramework Paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx) it include Example paging of Entityframework

Comment: tanx but i am using a stored procedure for paging now and i think this is the best kind of paging data whith sqlserver 2008 and another problem is the devxgrid control that is not like asp.net gridview